# Querying based on two files using for loop linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to use the for loop to query based on two variables... with the following command

```
for i in $(< enhancer.list)
do for j in $(< bp.list)
do
awk ' BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"};
{if ($1=="chr2" && $7<= $j && $8>= $j ) {print $0}}' $i.txt > $i.result.$j.txt
done;
done;
```

where "enhancer.list" is the filename; and the "bp.list" is a list of numbers that will be looked for in the files from enhancer.list.

I am not able to retrieve any line matching the awk query. Is it possible that $j is not working inside the brackets() Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assign `j` to an `awk` variable with the `-v` option.

```
awk -v j=$j ' 
    BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"};
    $1 == "chr2" && $7 <= $j && $8 >= j' $i.txt > $i.result.$j.txt
```

I left out `{print $0}` because that's the default action when the condition is true.